# Cannot get SOAP envelope body using Retrofit 2 and Simple XML Converter

Tags: android, xml, soap, retrofit, simple-framework

I am using Retrofit 2.2.0 and Retrofit SimpleXML Converter 2.2.0. I added `SimpleXmlConverter` to the `Retrofit` instance with the `addConverterFactory` method.

The problem is that when I receive the response, it gets the following error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Body' does not have a match in class ResponseEnvelope at line 1

I should get an XML response like this:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:autenticarUsuarioPorEmailResponse xmlns:ns="http://business.curitiba.org.br">
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2471:AutenticaUsuarioPorEmailSaida" xmlns:ax2471="http://saidas.curitiba.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2469="http://entities.curitiba.org/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ax2467="http://entradas.curitiba.org/xsd">
            <ax2471:idCredencial>3282</ax2471:idCredencial>
            <ax2471:tokenAcesso>635E3DA9-7C02-4DB7-9653-E7688C66B02C</ax2471:tokenAcesso>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:autenticarUsuarioPorEmailResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

#### ResponseEnvelope.java

```java
@Root(name = "soapenv:Envelope")
@Namespace(prefix = "soapenv", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
public class ResponseEnvelope {

    @Element(name = "soapenv:Body", required = false)
    private ResponseBody body;

    public ResponseBody getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(ResponseBody body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

#### ResponseBody.java

```java
@Root(name = "soapenv:Body", strict = false)
public class ResponseBody {

    @Element(name = "ns:cadastrarCredencialEmailResponse", required = false)
    private ResponseData requestData;

    public ResponseData getRequestData() {
        return requestData;
    }

    public void setRequestData(ResponseData requestData) {
        this.requestData = requestData;
    }

}
```

#### ResponseData.java

```java
@Root(name = "ns:cadastrarCredencialEmailResponse", strict = false)
@Namespace(prefix = "ns", reference = "http://business.curitiba.org")
public class ResponseData {

    @Element(name = "ns:return", required = false)
    private ResponseInfo info;

    public ResponseInfo getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(ResponseInfo info) {
        this.info = info;
    }
}
```

#### ResponseInfo.java

```java
@Root(name = "ns:return", strict = false)
@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace(prefix = "ax2471", reference = "http://saidas.curitiba.org/xsd"),
        @Namespace(prefix = "ax2469", reference = "http://entities.curitiba.org/xsd"),
        @Namespace(prefix = "xsi", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
        @Namespace(prefix = "ax2467", reference = "http://entradas.curitiba.org/xsd")
})
public class ResponseInfo {

    @Element(name = "ax2471:codigoAtivacao", required = false)
    private String codigoAtivacao;
    @Element(name = "ax2471:idCredencial", required = false)
    private String idCredencial;

    public String getCodigoAtivacao() {
        return codigoAtivacao;
    }

    public void setCodigoAtivacao(String codigoAtivacao) {
        this.codigoAtivacao = codigoAtivacao;
    }

    public String getIdCredencial() {
        return idCredencial;
    }

    public void setIdCredencial(String idCredencial) {
        this.idCredencial = idCredencial;
    }
}
```

I guess the problem is in the `ResponseInfo` class, that I don't know how to put the attribute `xsi:type` into it. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know how the Simple XML Converter works exactly, but element names are elements names, and they can be *prefixed*. This seems to be the confusion because the `:` character is used to delimit namespace prefixes and element names in physical XML document (tags).

You can just remove the "prefix" from the name and add the `@Namespace` annotation. For example:

#### ResponseEnvelope.java

```java
@Root(name = "Envelope")
@Namespace(prefix = "soapenv", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
final class ResponseEnvelope {

    @Element(name = "Body", required = false)
    @Namespace(prefix = "soapenv", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
    final ResponseBody body;

    private ResponseEnvelope(
            @Element(name = "Body") final ResponseBody body
    ) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

#### ResponseBody.java

```java
@Root(name = "Body", strict = false)
@Namespace(prefix = "soapenv", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
final class ResponseBody {

    @Element(name = "autenticarUsuarioPorEmailResponse", required = false)
    @Namespace(prefix = "ns", reference = "http://business.curitiba.org")
    final ResponseData requestData;

    private ResponseBody(
            @Element(name = "autenticarUsuarioPorEmailResponse") final ResponseData requestData
    ) {
        this.requestData = requestData;
    }

}
```

#### ResponseData.java

```java
@Root(name = "autenticarUsuarioPorEmailResponse", strict = false)
@Namespace(prefix = "ns", reference = "http://business.curitiba.org")
final class ResponseData {

    @Element(name = "return", required = false)
    @Namespace(prefix = "ns", reference = "http://business.curitiba.org")
    final ResponseInfo info;

    private ResponseData(
            @Element(name = "return") final ResponseInfo info
    ) {
        this.info = info;
    }

}
```

#### ResponseInfo.java

```java
@Root(name = "return", strict = false)
@Namespace(prefix = "ns", reference = "http://business.curitiba.org")
final class ResponseInfo {

    @Element(name = "tokenAcesso", required = false)
    @Namespace(prefix = "ax2471", reference = "http://saidas.curitiba.org/xsd")
    final String accessToken;

    @Element(name = "idCredencial", required = false)
    @Namespace(prefix = "ax2471", reference = "http://saidas.curitiba.org/xsd")
    final String credentialId;

    private ResponseInfo(
            @Element(name = "tokenAcesso") final String accessToken,
            @Element(name = "idCredencial") final String credentialId
    ) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
        this.credentialId = credentialId;
    }

}
```

So the following example:

```java
final ResponseInfo info = responseEnvelope.body.requestData.info;
System.out.println(info.accessToken);
System.out.println(info.credentialId);
```

will output:

> 635E3DA9-7C02-4DB7-9653-E7688C66B02C
>   3282

Comment: It throws this error "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Constructor not matched for class"

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808494/soap-api-calling-with-retrofit-getting-null-body-in-android this link and asnwer me.. I am too tired to check it on this

Comment: Hi, do I need to make ResponseBody and ResponseData class everytime new for a new web service? How do I convert it into some common structure? @LyubomyrShaydariv

Comment: You just made my day. Thanks for the answer @Lyubomyr.