# Can't get Soap list using Retrofit 2 and Simple XML Converter

Tags: android, soap, retrofit2, simple-framework

I'm trying to parse the next SOAP response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <tt_statemonitorMobileAdResponse xmlns="http://monitoring-gps.com.ua/aspservices/">
            <tt_statemonitorMobileAdResult>
                <statuscode>4</statuscode>
                <uiaction>0</uiaction>
                <data>
                    <anyType xsi:type="TtMobileStateData">
                        <tt_id>1000002502</tt_id>
                        <speed>0</speed>
                        <angle>0</angle>
                        <ign>0</ign>
                        <fuel>132</fuel>
                        <driver_id>-1</driver_id>
                        <satellites>20</satellites>
                        <driver />
                        <name>AA0873KT</name>
                        <lat>50.4441</lat>
                        <lon>30.6471</lon>
                        <date>07-10-2017 16:11:50</date>
                        <address>32, Гродненская улица, Дарница, Днепровский район, Киев, 02090, Украина</address>
                        <actual>1</actual>
                        <is_bs>0</is_bs>
                        <bsList />
                        <isMove>false</isMove>
                        <necessary_to_replace>false</necessary_to_replace>
                        <movesec>0</movesec>
                        <stopsec>20075</stopsec>
                        <devicetype_id>1</devicetype_id>
                        <devicetype>Автомобильный Трекер</devicetype>
                        <devicemodel_id>16</devicemodel_id>
                        <devicemodel>BI 864 TREK v2</devicemodel>
                        <battery_replacement />
                        <pointCount>0</pointCount>
                        <timeconnect>07.10.2017 16:11:24</timeconnect>
                    </anyType>
                    <anyType xsi:type="TtMobileStateData">
                        <tt_id>1000002514</tt_id>
                        <speed>69</speed>
                        <angle>147</angle>
                        <ign>1</ign>
                        <fuel>316</fuel>
                        <driver_id>-1</driver_id>
                        <satellites>20</satellites>
                        <driver />
                        <name>AA0872KT</name>
                        <lat>48.5748</lat>
                        <lon>23.0335</lon>
                        <date>07-10-2017 16:12:00</date>
                        <address>М-06, Свалявский район, Закарпатская область, 89308, Украина</address>
                        <actual>1</actual>
                        <is_bs>0</is_bs>
                        <bsList />
                        <isMove>true</isMove>
                        <necessary_to_replace>false</necessary_to_replace>
                        <movesec>1243</movesec>
                        <stopsec>0</stopsec>
                        <devicetype_id>1</devicetype_id>
                        <devicetype>Автомобильный Трекер</devicetype>
                        <devicemodel_id>16</devicemodel_id>
                        <devicemodel>BI 864 TREK v2</devicemodel>
                        <battery_replacement />
                        <pointCount>0</pointCount>
                        <timeconnect>07.10.2017 15:59:33</timeconnect>
                    </anyType>
                    <anyType xsi:type="TtMobileStateData">
                        <tt_id>1000002527</tt_id>
                        <speed>0</speed>
                        <angle>0</angle>
                        <ign>0</ign>
                        <fuel>172</fuel>
                        <driver_id>-1</driver_id>
                        <satellites>0</satellites>
                        <driver />
                        <name>AA2049EA</name>
                        <lat>50.444</lat>
                        <lon>30.647</lon>
                        <date>07-10-2017 16:09:56</date>
                        <address>32, Гродненская улица, Дарница, Днепровский район, Киев, 02090, Украина</address>
                        <actual>1</actual>
                        <is_bs>0</is_bs>
                        <bsList />
                        <isMove>false</isMove>
                        <necessary_to_replace>false</necessary_to_replace>
                        <movesec>0</movesec>
                        <stopsec>16120</stopsec>
                        <devicetype_id>1</devicetype_id>
                        <devicetype>Автомобильный Трекер</devicetype>
                        <devicemodel_id>16</devicemodel_id>
                        <devicemodel>BI 864 TREK v2</devicemodel>
                        <battery_replacement />
                        <pointCount>0</pointCount>
                        <timeconnect>07.10.2017 16:09:33</timeconnect>
                    </anyType>
                    <anyType xsi:type="TtMobileStateData">
                        <tt_id>1000003365</tt_id>
                        <speed>0</speed>
                        <angle>0</angle>
                        <ign>0</ign>
                        <fuel>0</fuel>
                        <driver_id>-1</driver_id>
                        <satellites>16</satellites>
                        <driver />
                        <name>Hilux 73</name>
                        <lat>49.5637</lat>
                        <lon>34.5297</lon>
                        <date>07-10-2017 16:12:17</date>
                        <address>Европейская улица, Полтава, Шевченковский район, Полтава, Полтавская область, 36000-36499, Украина</address>
                        <actual>1</actual>
                        <is_bs>0</is_bs>
                        <bsList />
                        <isMove>false</isMove>
                        <necessary_to_replace>false</necessary_to_replace>
                        <movesec>0</movesec>
                        <stopsec>89852</stopsec>
                        <devicetype_id>1</devicetype_id>
                        <devicetype>Автомобильный Трекер</devicetype>
                        <devicemodel_id>18</devicemodel_id>
                        <devicemodel>BI 820 TREK</devicemodel>
                        <battery_replacement />
                        <pointCount>0</pointCount>
                        <timeconnect>07.10.2017 14:43:32</timeconnect>
                    </anyType>
                </data>
                <length>4</length>
                <ttstates>
                    <tt_id>0</tt_id>
                    <speed>0</speed>
                    <angle>0</angle>
                    <ign>0</ign>
                    <fuel>0</fuel>
                    <driver_id>0</driver_id>
                    <satellites>0</satellites>
                    <lat>0</lat>
                    <lon>0</lon>
                    <actual>0</actual>
                    <is_bs>0</is_bs>
                    <isMove>false</isMove>
                    <necessary_to_replace>false</necessary_to_replace>
                    <movesec>0</movesec>
                    <stopsec>0</stopsec>
                    <devicetype_id>0</devicetype_id>
                    <devicemodel_id>0</devicemodel_id>
                    <pointCount>0</pointCount>
                </ttstates>
            </tt_statemonitorMobileAdResult>
        </tt_statemonitorMobileAdResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

For this purpose, I'm using Retrofit2 + Simple XML Converter.

Here are some Java classes.

**StatemonitorResponseData.java**

```
@Root(name = "data", strict = false)
public class StatemonitorResponseData {

    @ElementList(name = "anyType", required = false, inline = true)
    protected List<StatemonitorListModel> statemonitorList;

    public List<StatemonitorListModel> getStatemonitorList() {
        return statemonitorList;
    }

    public void setStatemonitorList(List<StatemonitorListModel> statemonitorList) {
        this.statemonitorList = statemonitorList;
    }
}
```

**StatemonitorListModel.java**

```
@Root(name = "anyType" , strict = false)
public class StatemonitorListModel {

    @Element(name = "tt_id")
    private int tt_id;

    @Element(name = "speed")
    private int speed;

    @Element(name = "angle")
    private int angle;

    @Element(name = "ign")
    private int ign;

    @Element(name = "fuel")
    private int fuel;

    @Element(name = "driver_id")
    private int driver_id;

    @Element(name = "satellites")
    private int satellites;

    @Element(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Element(name = "lat")
    private double lat;

    @Element(name = "lon")
    private double lon;

    @Element(name = "date")
    private String date;

    @Element(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Element(name = "actual")
    private int actual;

    @Element(name = "is_bs")
    private int is_bs;

    @Element(name = "isMove")
    private boolean isMove;

    @Element(name = "necessary_to_replace")
    private boolean necessary_to_replace;

    @Element(name = "movesec")
    private int movesec;

    @Element(name = "stopsec")
    private int stopsec;

    @Element(name = "devicetype_id")
    private int devicetype_id;

    @Element(name = "devicetype")
    private String devicetype;

    @Element(name = "devicemodel_id")
    private int devicemodel_id;

    @Element(name = "devicemodel")
    private String devicemodel;

    @Element(name = "pointCount")
    private int pointCount;

    @Element(name = "timeconnect")
    private String timeconnect;

    public int getTt_id() {
        return tt_id;
    }

    public void setTt_id(int tt_id) {
        this.tt_id = tt_id;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public int getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }

    public void setAngle(int angle) {
        this.angle = angle;
    }

    public int getIgn() {
        return ign;
    }

    public void setIgn(int ign) {
        this.ign = ign;
    }

    public int getFuel() {
        return fuel;
    }

    public void setFuel(int fuel) {
        this.fuel = fuel;
    }

    public int getDriver_id() {
        return driver_id;
    }

    public void setDriver_id(int driver_id) {
        this.driver_id = driver_id;
    }

    public int getSatellites() {
        return satellites;
    }

    public void setSatellites(int satellites) {
        this.satellites = satellites;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getActual() {
        return actual;
    }

    public void setActual(int actual) {
        this.actual = actual;
    }

    public int getIs_bs() {
        return is_bs;
    }

    public void setIs_bs(int is_bs) {
        this.is_bs = is_bs;
    }

    public boolean isMove() {
        return isMove;
    }

    public void setMove(boolean move) {
        isMove = move;
    }

    public boolean isNecessary_to_replace() {
        return necessary_to_replace;
    }

    public void setNecessary_to_replace(boolean necessary_to_replace) {
        this.necessary_to_replace = necessary_to_replace;
    }

    public int getMovesec() {
        return movesec;
    }

    public void setMovesec(int movesec) {
        this.movesec = movesec;
    }

    public int getStopsec() {
        return stopsec;
    }

    public void setStopsec(int stopsec) {
        this.stopsec = stopsec;
    }

    public int getDevicetype_id() {
        return devicetype_id;
    }

    public void setDevicetype_id(int devicetype_id) {
        this.devicetype_id = devicetype_id;
    }

    public String getDevicetype() {
        return devicetype;
    }

    public void setDevicetype(String devicetype) {
        this.devicetype = devicetype;
    }

    public int getDevicemodel_id() {
        return devicemodel_id;
    }

    public void setDevicemodel_id(int devicemodel_id) {
        this.devicemodel_id = devicemodel_id;
    }

    public String getDevicemodel() {
        return devicemodel;
    }

    public void setDevicemodel(String devicemodel) {
        this.devicemodel = devicemodel;
    }

    public int getPointCount() {
        return pointCount;
    }

    public void setPointCount(int pointCount) {
        this.pointCount = pointCount;
    }

    public String getTimeconnect() {
        return timeconnect;
    }

    public void setTimeconnect(String timeconnect) {
        this.timeconnect = timeconnect;
    }
```

Retrofit's response is successful but when I try to get the list it shows me the next error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.monitoring.gpsmayak.api.response.statemonitor.StatemonitorResponseData.getStatemonitorList()' on a null object reference
```

Please let me know what should I change in my code.
I'm not sure but I think the problem is that I don't know how to parse *xsi:type="TtMobileStateData"*.

I also found the similar problem here:
[Cannot get SOAP envelope body using Retrofit 2 and Simple XML Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457949/cannot-get-soap-envelope-body-using-retrofit-2-and-simple-xml-converter)
but I don't know how to implement this in my case

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved.
I just changed

```
@ElementList(name = "anyType", required = false, inline = true)
```

to

```
@ElementList(entry = "anyType", required = false, inline = true)
```